# How can I avoid entering password every time after wakeup from suspending in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, suspend

In Ubuntu 16.04, I can easily cancel the option "lock screen after wakeup from suspending" in the unity settings. But in Ubuntu 18.04 I can't find this option anywhere from the gnome settings to the gnome tweak tools. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable screen lock after suspend by installing dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

then navigate to

`org/gnome/desktop/screensaver` and turn off
`ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

For the CLI way, launch Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

Answer (score 1):

For the "point-and-click" way, open top-right menu (with the network/Wi-Fi, battery and/or volume icons, in the corner), click the "tools"/"spanner and screwdriver" icon (in the pop-up menu), click "Privacy" on the left and then click "Screen Lock" on the right.

[image: Privacy settinga]

From here, you can disable the screen lock or change the timeout to something longer (so there is a bigger delay before the screen is locked).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In GNOME desktop - in menu in right corner top - there is a little wheel for settings. Click there and then choose the settings for energy. There you can select the time Intervall for fading screen to "never".

This way you can lock the desktop off yourself, when you have lunch or a break. The lock for screen is in right corner above too.

Comment: There's no "wheel" in Ubuntu, nor are there "energy" settings... Are you referring to something else that uses "vanilla" GNOME?

Comment: I mean desktop of gnome, there where is a top edge. The right corner of top edge has a little menu. Below of menu there are three little icons. A little wheel for settings - a little lock for to shut off desktop - and a little switch for to shut down your machine.